# Clash polyglossia and pagenote?

Tags: polyglossia

I encounter a problem of which I speculate it might be a clash or bug in polyglossia.
In the MWE when `\usepackage{polyglossia}` is commented out, running `pdflatex` or `xelatex` yields the same `.ent` (endnote)file. (`PNTest.ent-pdflatex`, `PNTest.ent-xelatex1`)

When running `xelatex` with `\usepackage{polyglossia}` in force a different `.ent` file
is generated (`PNTest.ent-xelatex2`), which leads to error messages when this file
 is processed.

The code in the MWE is part of a larger package, but it boils down to this with
respect to the error I encounter.

Could some kind guru shed some light in the darkness?

MWE

File `PNTest.tex`

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[page,continuous]{pagenote}%

\renewcommand{\textinnotes}[1]{%      % remove [ ] in the marking text
 #1\quad%                             % and use an own format
}%
\renewcommand{\notenumintext}[1]{}%   skip the notemark in the text
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[2]{}%get rid of subhead in notelist


\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\vspace*{-2em}\Large\Dyn@Notesname}}
  \def\Dyn@Notes@Cnt{\thechapter}
  \newcommand{\Dyn@Notesname}{Annotations}
  \newcommand{\Dyn@Explanation}{for explanation}
  \newcommand{\Dyn@NoteName}{Annotation}
  \newcommand{\Dyn@NoteText}{see \Dyn@NoteName~\thepagenote\ on \Dyn@PageName}
  \newcommand{\Dyn@PageName}{page}

%
\NewDocumentCommand\DynNote{smO{\Dyn@Explanation}m}{%
% DynNote*{item}[expl]{description}
%        #1 #2    #3       #4
% 1) Typesets \footnote{expl}. If no <expl> is given, get it from the
%    default by calling \Dyn@Explanation.
% 2) Typesets a page- chap- or endnote with item\\description.
% Starred version
% 3) Adds (item,expl) to the wordlist with bold pageno. Note that it is
%    impossible to give a 'language' here. If no association exists, then
%    the association is made now.
%
%\typeout{DEBUG: \#1= #1,\#2= #2, \#3= #3, \#4= #4}
  \IfBooleanTF#1{% Star
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{\Dyn@Explanation}}%
     {\AddToList{#2}[\csname dynnotes@#2\endcsname|textbf]}%
     {\AddToList{#2}[#3|textbf]%
       \Associate{#2}{#3}}%
  }{}% [No]Star
%\typeout{DEBUG: pagenote 1}
  \pagenote[% Layout setup at customizing package pagenote
    \protect\needspace{3\baselineskip}%
    \hspace*{-1em}%
    \textbf{\protect\small\sffamily\Dyn@NoteName~\thepagenote}\\
    \textbf{\protect\footnotesize\sffamily#2}%
  ]{%
    \\%       insert a newline
    \protect\label{en:\Dyn@Notes@Cnt:\expandafter\thepagenote}%
    \sffamily%
    #4%
  }%
%\typeout{DEBUG: pagenote 2}
\footnote{#3, \Dyn@NoteText~\pageref{en:\Dyn@Notes@Cnt:\thepagenote}}%
%
%\par DEBUG: note:\Dyn@Notes@Cnt:\theendnote, en:\Dyn@Notes@Cnt:\theendnote
\xspace}% DynNote

\makeatother

\makepagenote

\begin{document}
Testin pagenotes
The .ent file is different when run pdflatex or xelatex

DynNote1\DynNote{DynExample1}[DynExplanation1]{DynText1}

\printnotes
\end{document}
```

File `PNTest.ent-pdflatex` / `PNTest.ent-xelatex1`

```
\noteentry{1}{\needspace {3\baselineskip }\hspace  *{-1em}\textbf  {\small \sffamily  Annotation\nobreakspace  {}1}\\ \textbf  {\footnotesize \sffamily  DynExample1}}{\\\label {en:0:1}\sffamily  DynText1}{1}
```

File `PNTest.ent-xelatex2`

```
\noteentry{1}{\needspace {3\baselineskip }\hspace  *{-1em}\textbf  {\small \sffamily  \def rm{sf}Annotation\nobreakspace {}1}\\ \textbf  {\footnotesize \sffamily  \def rm{sf}DynExample1}}{\\\label {en:0:1}\sffamily  \def rm{sf}DynText1}{1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug in `polyglossia` It makes `\sffamily` fragile.

It works if you change your test file to look like:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\typeout{\meaning\sffamily}
\protected\edef\sffamily{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\sffamily}}
\typeout{\meaning\sffamily}
```

Comment: @Jack you could report it to the package maintainer.

Comment: I would, if I only knew the maintainers mail address

Comment: @Jack surprisingly hard to find in the package doc:-) but I guess you are supposed to add an issue here https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia

Comment: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/90

Comment: Glad to see you reported it yourself on github.